# xcode 4.3.2 fails to launch

Tags: xcode, monodevelop

I installed the most recent Monodevelop (3.0.1) I could find and installed Monodevelop but when I double click on an xlb file I see the following error:

error updating Objective-C type information. operation is not supported

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5167) that was fixed in MonoDevelop 3.0.2, please update.

Answer (score 0):

3.0.2 seems to have the same problem once you install but the problem seems to go away after MonoDevelop and XCode relaunched again.